# Login to a remote desktop using MSTSCLib

Tags: c#, remote-desktop, rdp

I am trying to log in on a remote desktop. I am able to open the login screen with the following code. (rdpSP is a Microsoft Terminal Server Client Control - version 1)

```
  rdpSP.Server = "the IP";
  rdpSP.Domain = "the domain";
  rdpSP.UserName = "the username";
  MSTSCLib.IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (MSTSCLib.IMsTscNonScriptable)rdpSP.GetOcx();
  secured.ClearTextPassword = "the password";
  rdpSP.Width = this.Width;
  rdpSP.Height = this.Height;
  rdpSP.Connect();
```

Now I can see the login screen and the user domain/username. But the password isn't used.
Is it possible to log in automaticly or at least fill in the password?

Comment: It has a lot of events, they tell you what went wrong.  If you don't subscribe them then you can't tell what the problem might be.

Comment: what event should i try? I used onconnecting and onconnected but nothing seems to be wrong

Comment: The ones that report errors should be on the top of your list.  OnLogonError, OnFatalError, OnWarning.

Comment: None of those events get called so I don't think it has an error

Comment: I do think it is a server settings to _not_ accept the provided password and to force a user to enter it manually.

Comment: where can i find those server settings?

Comment: I only do have a German server at my fingertips. [It is an option here](http://i.imgur.com/pBQQag7.png). Please also [read the TechNet documentation about the group policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771869(v=ws.10).aspx). It is called "Always prompt for password upon connection".

Comment: Yes this is checked on. Does it give any security issues when I turn this off?

Answer (score 1):

The password should be saved in the form `rdpSP.AdvancedSettings9.ClearTextPassword`